# Fullcalendar - get data about a background event (constraint) when external event is dragged onto it

Tags: fullcalendar

Has anyone tried to do this and had success?

I drag an external event on top of a background event that is being used as a constraint. I wish to get data from bg event that I just dropped onto.

Essentially, my bg rendered event contains some custom fields that would be really handy to use within my calendarEventReceive() function.

I see that the event object passed does show constraint id. Unfortunately, and perhaps something i should fix - several bg rendered events share the same id so the constraint can be used in multiple places in the week.

Just curious if anyone has done something similar